# get the value of first column of selected row from datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am making a picker control and i want to get the value of first column of selected row from datatable, it works fine initially but when i use paging.,It does not works. Please suggest something. here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#example').dataTable({"sPaginationType": "full_numbers","iDisplayLength": 10,});
    $('#example tr').click(function ()
    {
        var queryString = window.location.search.substring(1);
        if ($(this).find('th:first').attr('id') != "th")
        {
            window.opener.document.getElementById(queryString).value = $(this).find('td:first').text();
            window.close();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably the new elements are formed dynamically..try

```
$('#example').delegate('tr','click',function () {
                                var queryString = window.location.search.substring(1);
                                if ($(this).find('th:first').attr('id') != "th") {
                                    window.opener.document.getElementById(queryString).value = $(this).find('td:first').text();
                                    window.close();
                                }
            });
```